# Date Difference between rows for each id SQL

Tags: sql, db2

I have a query that produces data in the following format:

```
ID | DATE                       | STATUS
---+----------------------------+----------
93 | 2018-02-01 14:23:31.90123  | DRAFT
94 | 2018-02-01 14:23:32.44114  | DRAFT
94 | 2018-02-01 16:06:57.971881 | SUBMITTED
94 | 2018-02-01 16:07:25.940212 | REROUTE
94 | 2018-02-01 16:07:25.940212 | SUBMITTED
95 | 2018-02-01 14:24:51.749198 | DRAFT
```

I am trying to structure another query that will take this data and calculate the difference between each date. The ultimate goal is to figure out how long each *ID* is stuck in a specific *STATUS*. Does anyone have any ideas on how to go about doing this? The initial query already orders the data by *ID* and *DATE*.

Comment: What operating-system runs your Db2-server? What is the version/fixpack of the Db2-server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lag()`:

```
select t.*, lag(datetime) over (partition by id order by datetime) as prev_datetime
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

@JOSHUA; Here is the query and I test using ORACLE. Hope it helps. Thanks!

```
select ID,
DATETIME,
STATUS,
ROUND(24*60*60*(DATETIME - LAG(DATETIME) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATETIME)),2) AS TIME_DIFF_SEC
FROM TABLE
```

Result:

```
ID  DATETIME                STATUS      TIME_DIFF_SEC
93  2018-02-01T14:23:31Z    DRAFT       (null)
94  2018-02-01T14:23:32Z    DRAFT       (null)
94  2018-02-01T16:06:57Z    SUBMITTED   6205
94  2018-02-01T16:07:25Z    REROUTE       28
94  2018-02-01T16:07:25Z    SUBMITTED      0
95  2018-02-01T14:24:51Z    DRAFT       (null)
```

Comment: Date arithmetic in DB2 [returns a formatted value](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_datearithmetic.html), not a straight numeric count - the multiplication would be nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

Other method if your system dont have lag option

```
select f1.*, f2.*
from yourtable f1
left outer join lateral
(
    select * from yourtable f0
    where f0.id=f1.id and rrn(f1)<>rrn(f0)
    order by f0.DATE desc 
    fetch first rows only                      

) f2 on 1=1
```